# Extjs 6.0 collapse/ expand issue on internet explorer

Tags: extjs, internet-explorer-11, treepanel

I'm having some issue when a tree panel collapses, the header panel disappears, but when it expands it works fine. This is only happens on IE 11.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please share your code or an fiddler so we can understand your query in better way and help you.

Comment: @developernewbie: Please Provide Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE

Comment: How is this related to C#6?